# Retrieving html elements inside a html table cell

Tags: javascript

I've got an html table.  In my application, I'm dynamically adding divs within an application.  It gives the user an optical view of their application.

I'm trying to parse the html table data and I'm having a problem.

Here is my first attempt:

```
var tblworkout = document.getElementById("tblWorkout");
for (i = 1; i < tblworkout.rows.length; i++) {
    console.log("table row count:" + i)
    for (j = 1; j < tblworkout.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
        console.log("td count for row " + i + ": " + j);

        for (k = 0; tblworkout.rows[i].cells[j].getElementsByTagName("div").length; k++) {
            console.log("div count for td " + j + ": " + k);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the second attempt:

```
var tblworkout = document.getElementById("tblWorkout");
for (i = 1; i < tblworkout.rows.length; i++) {
    console.log("table row count:" + i)
    for (j = 1; j < tblworkout.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
        console.log("td count for row " + i + ": " + j);

        var tdhtml = tblworkout.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML;
        console.log(tdhtml);

        for (k = 0; k < tdhtml.getElementsByTagName("div").length; k++) {
            console.log(k);
        }

    }
}
```

The second attempt is getting me closer, but it turns out you can't use getElementsByTagName in an html string.

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Don't do innerHTML first. Cell is a DOM object which you can use getElementsByTagName on

Comment: `var tdhtml = tblworkout.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML;` to `var tdhtml = tblworkout.rows[i].cells[j];`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse innerHTML, just query elements inside every `td`:

```
var tblworkout = document.getElementById("tblWorkout");
for (var i = 1; i < tblworkout.rows.length; i++) {
    console.log("table row count:" + i)
    for (j = 1; j < tblworkout.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
        console.log("td count for row " + i + ": " + j);

        var td = tblworkout.rows[i].cells[j];
        var divs = td.getElementsByTagName("div"); // <-- select divs collection in td

        console.log(divs);

        for (var k = 0; k < divs.length; k++) {
            console.log(divs[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

And don't forget to put `var` when you declare variables in loops, otherwise you declare them in global scope.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just your goal to iterate over each `<div>` which is a child of the `<td>`s of your `<table>`, consider using [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
var div = document.querySelectorAll(
    '#tblWorkout > tr > td > div, ' +
    '#tblWorkout > tbody > tr > td > div' // tables are supposed to have <tbody>s ;)
);
console.log('Found ' + div.length + ' <div>s');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < div.length; ++i) {
    console.log(div);
}
```